# Remote into Server

Tags: perl, unix, cygwin, ksh

I want to remote into the KornShell (ksh) of a Unix server from a Windows box, I did this using perl and cygwin, is there another way of doing this and then after run several Unix commands from a text file or what not. I want to run commands such as source and logging in with a password.

Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks

Comment: this feels like it should be on serverfault

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need an [SSH client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh_client). Last time I used Windows as a client, I used [putty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), but it might not be very scriptable. (I don't know if anything can beat the [original OpenSSH](http://openssh.org/windows.html) for good scriptability, though installing Cygwin just to run it might be a bit extreme.)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can directly do the telnet  from windows